# Adjust a simple form fields value with a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

First of all I'm very new to react-admin.

I've got a SimpleForm which populates a bunch of fields from an API call -

```
<SimpleForm noValidate toolbar={<PostEditToolbar />}>
      <TextInput source="minute" label="Minute" />
      <TextInput source="hour" label="Hour" />
      <TextInput source="day" label="Day" />
```

I want to include some buttons on this edit page which will set the values of these fields, and I've done the following:

```
 <Button class="btn btn-success"
       onClick={() => { document.getElementById("hour").value = '1'; }}
      label="Weekly">
```

The button updates the field, but as soon as you click in the input field it reverts back to the previous entered value (even if you don't save it).    If you click save, it'll just revert back to the previous values as well.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Entire code:

```
export const BackupconfigEdit = (props) => (
  <div>
  <Edit {...props}>

    <SimpleForm noValidate toolbar={<PostEditToolbar />}>
      <TextInput source="minute" label="Minute" />
      <TextInput source="hour" label="Hour" />
      <TextInput source="day" label="Day" />
      <TextInput source="month" label="Month" />
      <TextInput source="week" label="Week" />
      <Button class="btn btn-success"
       onClick={() => { document.getElementById("hour").value = '1'; document.getElementById("minute").value = 0; document.getElementById("day").value = 0; document.getElementById("month").value = 0; document.getElementById("week").value = 0;}}
      label="Weekly">
    </Button>

    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With React, you don't change the DOM imperatively (as you did with `document.getElementById("hour").value = '1'`). Instead, you update a model that React automatically renders into the DOM.

In the case of forms in react-admin, the model is handled by a library called react-hook-form. This library exposes a hook allowing to manipulate the form value, called `useFormContext`. You need to call this hook to change an input value:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Edit, SimpleForm, TextInput } from "react-admin";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

const WeeklyButton = () => {
  const { setValue } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        setValue("hour", "1");
        setValue("minute", 0);
        setValue("day", 0);
        setValue("month", 0);
        setValue("week", 0);
      }}
    >
      Weekly
    </Button>
  );
};

const BackupconfigEdit = () => (
  <div>
    <Edit>
      <SimpleForm noValidate>
        <TextInput source="minute" label="Minute" />
        <TextInput source="hour" label="Hour" />
        <TextInput source="day" label="Day" />
        <TextInput source="month" label="Month" />
        <TextInput source="week" label="Week" />
        <WeeklyButton />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
  </div>
);

export default BackupconfigEdit;
```

Check the react-hook form documentation for details (https://react-hook-form.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution first, secondly this will only update the value of the input but the submit remains disabled, is there any way it will consider form as dirty or touched?

Comment: There is a shouldDirty option in react-hook-form like this:

setValue('name', 'value', { shouldDirty: true })