# Dynamically change formdata in ReactAdmin v4

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, react-hook-form

We have a rather complex **Create** form which has an input field that is calculated by other input fields in this form.

We use `FormDataConsumer` to read the current form data, however if we change the given `formData` or `scopedFormData` the calculated input remains unchanged.
We also tried to use `useWatch` or `watch` from the already used `react-hook-form` lib but the callback isn't called when the user makes inputs.

We also tried the React Admin `useInput` but don't know how to pass a custom `onChange` event. In the [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#the-useinput-hook) is only the passing of the already applied `onChange` method described.

How can we change this input fields value, when other input fields change (`promoPartner`, `locale` and `endDateEnabled`)? The calculated field has to be sent within the form submit too.

Here is [the codebox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-payne-9818hl?file=/src/CampaignCreate.js)

Comment: Could you reduce your example to just the thing that doesn't work? There are dozen inputs in your example, it's hard to understand what goes wrong.

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto Thanks for your response. I simplified it as far as I could, but we need the value of several fields in different technical places. We need the value of the `promoPartner` of the first tab but also the `locale` field of the **ArrayInput**. As well we need to watch if the `endDateEnabled` is checked to wether send the `endDate` to the API or not.

Comment: check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72725105/adjust-a-simple-form-fields-value-with-a-button, it may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @RathviBharat , this would help us setting the value in general, but we need to set it when other field values change, so we still need something like an `onChange` event