# React-Admin update <TextField> based on <SelectInput>

Tags: react-admin

I have the following code for a meal planner app:

```
<ReferenceInput source="tuesday.breakfast" reference="recipes">
<AutocompleteInput optionText="name" optionValue='id' fullWidth/>
</ReferenceInput>
```

which provides the user with a drop down of recipes to choose from

[image]

The data looks like this

```
{
"id" = 456432b33c43ds1
"name" = "porridge"
"calories" = 675
}
```

This works the way I expect, in that it saves the id into my database.

But I want to display the calories above the drop down in a `<TextField>` which is updated anytime the user changes the drop down choice on the edit page?

Comment: Chris, checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72725105/adjust-a-simple-form-fields-value-with-a-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use react-hook-form's `useWatch` hook, which watches a field in the form, and forces a rerender of the component it's used in. It will allow you to access the *value* stored in the form - in your case, the recipe id. Then, you'll have to *fetch* the actual recipe with. `useGetOne`. Don't worry about overfetching - react-admin will deduplicate requests to the data provider, and it should only call `dataProvider.getOne()` once.

So create a custom field component watching the source, as follows:

```
import { useWatch } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useGetOne } from 'react-admin';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';

const CaloriesField = () => {
   const recipeId = useWatch({ name: 'tuesday.breakfast' });
   const { data: recipe, loading } = useGetOne('recipes', { id: recipeId });
   return loading ? null : (
       <Typography>
          {recipe.calories}
       </Typography>
   );
};
```

More details about useWatch here: https://react-hook-form.com/api/usewatch

Comment: Thank you so much Francois, I'll give this a try later but that looks like exactly what I'm after!

Comment: Works perfectly and helped me solve another problem I was having - thank you!!